# Batch wise batch normalization in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What is the correct way of performing batch wise batch normalization in TensorFlow? (I.e. I don't want to compute a running mean and variance). My current implementation is based on [`tf.nn.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization), where `x`is the output of a convolutional layer with shape `[batch_size, width, height, num_channels]`. I want to perform batch norm channel wise.

```
batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[0, 1, 2])
x = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, batch_mean, batch_var, offset=0, scale=0, variance_epsilon=1e-6)
```

But the results of this implementation are very bad. Comparison with `tensorflow.contrib.slim.batch_norm` shows that it is fare inferior (similarly bad training performance).

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and what can explain this bad performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by @Maosi works, but I found that it is slow. The following is simple and fast.

```
batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[0, 1, 2])
x = tf.subtract(x, batch_mean)
x = tf.div(x, tf.sqrt(batch_var) + 1e-6)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may consider `tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm`. You may want to reshape `x` to [batch, channel, width, height] and set `begin_norm_axis=2` for channel wise normalization (each batch and each channel will be normalized independently).

Here is example how to reshape from your original order to [batch, channel, width, height]:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

batch = 2
height = 2
width = 2
channel = 3

tot_size = batch * height * channel * width

ts_4D_bhwc = tf.reshape(tf.range(tot_size), [batch, height, width, channel])
ts_4D_bchw = tf.transpose(ts_4D_bhwc, perm=[0,3,1,2])

print("Original tensor w/ order bhwc\n")
print(ts_4D_bhwc.eval())

print("\nTransormed tensor w/ order bchw\n")
print(ts_4D_bchw.eval())
```

Outputs:

```
Original tensor w/ order bhwc

[[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]]

  [[ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]]]


 [[[12 13 14]
   [15 16 17]]

  [[18 19 20]
   [21 22 23]]]]

Transormed tensor w/ order bchw

[[[[ 0  3]
   [ 6  9]]

  [[ 1  4]
   [ 7 10]]

  [[ 2  5]
   [ 8 11]]]


 [[[12 15]
   [18 21]]

  [[13 16]
   [19 22]]

  [[14 17]
   [20 23]]]]
```

Comment: I have always felt uncomfortable with the reshape. Can you show how you would do it?